# Alamofire from Pods - Library not loaded error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, alamofire

I wonder if anyone could makes Alamofire from Pods works? Because  all my friends NOT.

Steps to reproduce from Alamofire github page:

> $ gem install cocoapods --pre
>
> To integrate Alamofire into your Xcode project using CocoaPods,
>   specify it in your Podfile:
>
> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' platform :ios, '8.0'
>
> pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
>
> Then, run the following command:
>
> $ pod install

Everything works fine if you run on device connected to Xcode.
But if Archive and make ipa  - you always got

**Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
   Reason: no suitable image found.**

So anyony know the secret? ))) Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions that pop up when you google "no suitable image found"?

Comment: I hope you are facing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173654/error-library-not-loaded-when-launching-app

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely relating you your apple developer certificate. You better go to keychain app and check it for validity of your certificate.

I had the same issue. Also check for the **Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority** in the Key chain.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are at least on CocoaPods `0.36.0.beta2`. If it's still not resolved, check out https://github.com/CocoaPods/swift/issues/19.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by revoking and re-requesting the certificate. It's a bug in Xcode.